# Как записать в фрейм сроки с учетом индексов (строки могут быть пустые)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, обработка-данных

Задача следующая: есть Excel файл, где пропущены значения адресов. Эти ячейки нужны! Нужно перезаписать файл и добавить широту и долготу указанного адреса. В пустых ячейках надо написать: "Нет полного адреса".

[Пример данных](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jyz7c1Y1t5ODuRCWFpEuYW6VA8cv3YrsTdFyDHCS20o/edit?usp=sharing).

Код ниже работает и выводит адреса:

```
    str_listik = []
Index =[]

for index,line in  enumerate(df['Адрес объекта'].head(100)):
    if line==1:
        
        #df2.loc[index].Index = index
        #print(index)
        Index.append(index)
        pass
    else:
        listik = []
        for index2, paramValue in enumerate(addr_extractor.find(line).fact.parts):
            p=paramValue
            i = index2
            
            if p.type=='индекс':
                listik.append( p.value)
            if p.type=='город':
                listik.append( p.value)
            if p.type=='улица':
                listik.append( p.value)
            if p.type=='дом':
                listik.append( p.value )
            if  p.type=='корпус':
                listik.append( p.value )
            
            
    str_listik.append(' '.join(map(str,listik)))
str_listik
```

Но, когда я применяю функцию:

```
str_listik = []
Index =[]
def parse(string):
    if string != 1 or string != None :
        listik = []
        for index2, paramValue in enumerate(addr_extractor.find(string).fact.parts):
            p=paramValue
            i = index2
            Index.append(index2)
            if p.type=='индекс':
                listik.append( p.value)
            if p.type=='город':
                listik.append( p.value)
            if p.type=='улица':
                listik.append( p.value)
            if p.type=='дом':
                listik.append( p.value)
            if  p.type=='корпус':
                listik.append( p.value)
            
        #str_listik.append(' '.join(map(str,listik)))
        return (' '.join(map(str,listik)))
    else:
        return None
    


df2['Address'] = df2['Адрес объекта'].apply(parse)

df2.head(10)
```

То выходит ошибка:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-4dc7bcbf5c95> in <module>
     26 
     27 
---> 28 df2['Address'] = df2['Адрес объекта'].apply(parse)
     29 
     30 df2.head(10)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   3846             else:
   3847                 values = self.astype(object).values
-> 3848                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   3849 
   3850         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas\_libs\lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-9-4dc7bcbf5c95> in parse(string)
      4     if string != 1 or string != None :
      5         listik = []
----> 6         for index2, paramValue in enumerate(addr_extractor.find(string).fact.parts):
      7             p=paramValue
      8             i = index2

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\natasha\extractors.py in find(self, text)
     74 
     75     def find(self, text):
---> 76         matches = list(self(text))
     77         if not matches:
     78             return

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\natasha\extractors.py in __call__(self, text)
     41 
     42     def __call__(self, text):
---> 43         for match in self.parser.findall(text):
     44             yield adapt_match(match)
     45 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yargy\parser.py in findall(self, text)
    287 
    288     def findall(self, text):
--> 289         states = self.matches(text)
    290         trees = prepare_trees(states)
    291         trees = sorted(trees)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yargy\parser.py in matches(self, text, all)
    274 
    275     def matches(self, text, all=True):
--> 276         chart = self.chart(text, all=all)
    277         return (
    278             chart

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yargy\parser.py in chart(self, text, all)
    258         tokens = self.tokenizer(text)
    259         tokens = self.tagger(tokens)
--> 260         chart = Chart(tokens)
    261         for column, next_column in chart:
    262             if column.first or all:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yargy\parser.py in __init__(self, tokens)
     25 class Chart(object):
     26     def __init__(self, tokens):
---> 27         self.tokens = list(tokens)
     28 
     29         self.columns = [Column(0, None)]

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yargy\tagger.py in __call__(self, tokens)
     13 class PassTagger(Tagger):
     14     def __call__(self, tokens):
---> 15         for token in tokens:
     16             yield token
     17 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yargy\tokenizer.py in __call__(self, text)
    119     def __call__(self, text):
    120         tokens = Tokenizer.__call__(self, text)
--> 121         for token in tokens:
    122             if token.type == RUSSIAN:
    123                 forms = self.morph(token.value)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yargy\tokenizer.py in __call__(self, text)
     97 
     98     def __call__(self, text):
---> 99         for match in re.finditer(self.regexp, text):
    100             name = match.lastgroup
    101             value = match.group(0)

~\anaconda3\lib\re.py in finditer(pattern, string, flags)
    246 
    247     Empty matches are included in the result."""
--> 248     return _compile(pattern, flags).finditer(string)
    249 
    250 def compile(pattern, flags=0):

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: скопируйте текс ошибки целиком

Comment: В `df2` у вас одна строка всего. Вы не можете по индексу 1 там ничего найти. Используйте `pd.concat`, например. Но вообще не очень понятно, что у вас вообще в коде происходит. Возможно, лучше в исходном `df` что-то менять.

Comment: @Интик  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\range.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
    349             try:
--> 350                 return self._range.index(new_key)
    351             except ValueError:

ValueError: 1 is not in range

KeyError: 1

Comment: @CrazyElf я бы хотела в исходном df поменять, но я не знаю, каким образом это сделать? Я создаю список обработанных адресов(строки), в них нет индекса. Так вот , как я могу записать без индекса эти строки в начальный датафрейм?

Comment: @MaxU добавила ошибку и немного изменила вопрос

Comment: Сложно будет вам помочь без __воспроизводимого__ примера данных

Comment: @MaxU, добавила ссылку на файл

Comment: @ElenaBarbanova Как понял, более помог последний ответ. Вы можете отменить принятие первого ответа, и после, принять другой ответ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Слегка оптимизированный вариант решения - создаем словарь - базу данных уже распарсенных адресов и, в том случае если такой адрес мы уже парсили, просто возвращаем результат из БД:

```
DB_ADDR = {}

PART_TYPES = [
    "индекс", "город", 
    "улица", "проспект", "шоссе", "переулок", "проезд",
    "дом", "корпус"
]


def parse_addr(
        addr_str, 
        addr_extractor=addr_extractor, 
        db_addr=DB_ADDR, 
        min_addr_len=10
):
    if not addr_str or len(str(addr_str)) < min_addr_len:
        return None
    ext = addr_extractor.find(addr_str)
    if not ext:
        return None
    addr_str_lower = addr_str.casefold()
    if not addr_str_lower in DB_ADDR:
        DB_ADDR[addr_str_lower] = {part.type: part.value for part in ext.fact.parts}
    return DB_ADDR[addr_str_lower]


def combine_addr_str(parsed_addr, part_types=PART_TYPES):
    if not parsed_addr:
        return None
    return " ".join(
        parsed_addr[part_type]
        for part_type in part_types
        if parsed_addr.get(part_type)
    )

    
def get_addr_str(addr_str):
    return combine_addr_str(parse_addr(addr_str, db_addr=DB_ADDR))


df = pd.read_excel(filename).iloc[:100]
df["Address"] = [get_addr_str(x) for x in df["Адрес объекта"]]
```

результат:

```
In [289]: df
Out[289]: 
                                        Адрес объекта                           Address
0   ЮВАО, 109469, г Москва, Марьино, ул Марьинский...  109469 Москва Марьинский Парк 21
1   ЗАО, г Москва, Очаково-Матвеевское, ул Очаковс...             Москва Очаковская Б 2
2   ТАО, 108828, г. Москва, с Былово, Краснопахорс...          108828 Москва Радужная 7
3   ЗАО, 119571, г Москва, Тропарево-Никулино, пр-...      119571 Москва Вернадского 94
4   ЮВАО, г Москва, Люблино, ул Ставропольская, д....        Москва Ставропольская 23/1
..                                                ...                               ...
95  ЮАО, 115304, г Москва, Царицыно, ул Кантемиров...    115304 Москва Кантемировская 5
96  ЦАО, 105005, г Москва, Басманный, ул Радио, д....            105005 Москва Радио 10
97                                                  1                              None
98                                                  1                              None
99                                                  1                              None

[100 rows x 2 columns]
```

PS в приведенном в вопросе примере данных ~25% адресов дублируются.

Comment: спасибо, а Вы случайно не подскажите, как адрес , который содержит 'Волынская 1-я ..." заменить на "1-я Волынская", у меня иначе длгота и широта не выводятся)))

Comment: #df[(df['Address'].str.contains('1-я Вольская') == True)] = np.where((df['Address'].str.contains('Вольская 1-я') == True), 'Вольская 1-я', '1-я Вольская')

Comment: например, выше заменяет строку "Волынская 1-я д 32" на "1-я Волынская"

Comment: @ElenaBarbanova, советую открыть новый вопрос с несколькими примерами (когда заменяемая часть находится в начале/середине/конце строки) 

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1237914/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%84%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b9%d0%bc%d0%b0

Answer (score 4):

Модуль `natasha` работает очень медленно, поэтому в решении ниже я показал как это сделать для первых 100 строк файла.
Для ваших реальных данных удалите `.iloc[:100]` и после запуска скрипта, советую пойти пить кофе или отдохнуть... ;)

```
def parse_addr(addr_str, addr_extractor=addr_extractor):
    ext = addr_extractor.find(addr_str)
    if not ext:
        return None
    return {part.type: part.value for part in ext.fact.parts}
    
def combine_addr_str(parsed_addr):
    if not parsed_addr:
        return None
    res = ""
    if parsed_addr.get("индекс"):
        res += parsed_addr.get("индекс")
    if parsed_addr.get("город"):
        res += (" " if res else "") + parsed_addr.get("город")
    if parsed_addr.get("улица"):
        res += (" " if res else "") + parsed_addr.get("улица")
    if parsed_addr.get("дом"):
        res += (" " if res else "") + parsed_addr.get("дом")
    if parsed_addr.get("корпус"):
        res += (" " if res else "") + parsed_addr.get("корпус")
    return res
    
df = pd.read_excel(filename).iloc[:100] # <--- выбираем первые 100 строк файла
# df = pd.read_excel(filename) # <--- для реальных данных используйте эту строку вместо предыдущей

mask = df["Адрес объекта"].str.len() > 10


df["Address"] = np.nan
df.loc[mask, "Address"] = df.loc[mask, "Адрес объекта"].map(lambda x: combine_addr_str(parse_addr(x)))
```

результат:

```
In [118]: df
Out[118]: 
                                        Адрес объекта                           Address
0   ЮВАО, 109469, г Москва, Марьино, ул Марьинский...  109469 Москва Марьинский Парк 21
1   ЗАО, г Москва, Очаково-Матвеевское, ул Очаковс...             Москва Очаковская Б 2
2   ТАО, 108828, г. Москва, с Былово, Краснопахорс...          108828 Москва Радужная 7
3   ЗАО, 119571, г Москва, Тропарево-Никулино, пр-...                  119571 Москва 94
4   ЮВАО, г Москва, Люблино, ул Ставропольская, д....        Москва Ставропольская 23/1
..                                                ...                               ...
95  ЮАО, 115304, г Москва, Царицыно, ул Кантемиров...    115304 Москва Кантемировская 5
96  ЦАО, 105005, г Москва, Басманный, ул Радио, д....            105005 Москва Радио 10
97                                                  1                               NaN
98                                                  1                               NaN
99                                                  1                               NaN

[100 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: спасибо Вам огромное!

Comment: @ElenaBarbanova, всегда пожалуйста) Кстати, благодаря вашей задаче, я заинтересовался тем как можно параллельно обрабатывать Pandas объекты медленными невекторизированными функциями. Если найду рабочий вариант то дам вам знать... ;)

Comment: @ Здорово, спасибо!

Comment: случайно не знаете, если в облаке запуститьь программу, быстрее отработает?

Comment: @ElenaBarbanova, если в облаке CPU быстрее чем у вас на локальной машине, то да) PS количество ядер и процессоров для данного решения иррелевантно

Comment: @ElenaBarbanova, [рекомендую посмотреть ;)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1237900/211923)